# How delete all subpages tree when admin click "delete page" (using wp hooks like delete_post or other)

Tags: wordpress, children

I want force  delete  all child pages  on  parent page delete action in  admin

What can you  suggest people?

Answer (score 1):

@valir, I just released a plugin called "Completely Delete": http://wordpress.org/plugins/completely-delete/. It is made for exactly what you'd like to do. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_parent' => $parentid,
    'post_type' => 'page'
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );

if (is_array($posts) && count($posts) > 0) {

// Delete all the Children of the Parent Page
foreach($posts as $post){

    wp_delete_post($post->ID, true);

}}

// Delete the Parent Page
wp_delete_post($parentid, true);
```